# Class<?>.isAnnotationPresent returns false for annotated class

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

I have my own annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface Component {
}
```

And class:

```
package com.ltp.analog.test;

import com.ltp.analog.core.annotation.Component;

@Component
public class TestOne {

    public void test(){
        System.out.println("TEST ONE");
    }

}
```

Also implemented custom ClassLoader:

```
package com.ltp.analog.reflection;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class AnalogClassLoader extends ClassLoader{

    @Override
    public Class findClass(String name) {
        Class cl = findLoadedClass(name);

        if(cl != null){
            return cl;
        }

        byte[] b = loadClassFromFile(name);
        return defineClass(name, b, 0, b.length);
    }

    private byte[] loadClassFromFile(String fileName)  {
        InputStream inputStream = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(
                fileName.replaceAll("[.]", "/") + ".class");
        byte[] buffer;
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int nextValue = 0;
        try {
            while ( (nextValue = inputStream.read()) != -1 ) {
                byteStream.write(nextValue);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        buffer = byteStream.toByteArray();
        return buffer;
    }

}
```

And `ReflectionUtils` class which have to load all the classes in package recursively:

```
package com.ltp.analog.reflection;

import com.ltp.analog.Testing;
import com.ltp.analog.reflection.qualifier.ClassQualifier;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class ReflectionUtils {

    private static final AnalogClassLoader cl = new AnalogClassLoader();

    public static List<Class> getClassesInPackageRecursively(String packName){
        List<String> packs = getSubpackagesRecursively(packName);

        List<Class> result = new LinkedList<>();

        packs.forEach(pack -> result.addAll(getClassesInPackage(pack)));

        return result.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static List<Class> getClassesInPackage(String packName){
        if(packName == null || packName.isEmpty()){
            return List.of();
        }

        URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource(packName.replaceAll("[.]", "/"));

        if(url == null){
            return List.of();
        }

        File pack = new File(url.getPath());

        if(!pack.isDirectory() || pack.listFiles() == null){
            return List.of();
        }

        return Arrays.stream(pack.listFiles())
                .filter(File::isFile)
                .filter(f -> f.getName().endsWith(".class"))
                .map(f -> cl.findClass(packName + "." + f.getName().substring(0, f.getName().indexOf('.'))))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static List<String> getSubpackagesRecursively(String packName){
        List<String> result = new LinkedList<>();

        for(String pack : getSubpackages(packName)){
            List<String> subPacks = getSubpackagesRecursively(pack);
            result.addAll(subPacks);
        }

        result.add(packName);

        return result.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static List<String> getSubpackages(String packName){
        if(packName == null || packName.isEmpty()){
            return List.of();
        }

        URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource(packName.replaceAll("[.]", "/"));

        if(url == null){
            return List.of();
        }

        File pack = new File(url.getPath());

        if(!pack.isDirectory() || pack.listFiles() == null){
            return List.of();
        }

        return Arrays.stream(pack.listFiles())
                .filter(File::isDirectory)
                .map(f -> packName + "." + f.getName())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private ReflectionUtils(){}

}
```

The problem is that after loading all the classes in the passed package I'm trying to filter them and get only annotated by `@Component`, but the result is weird:

`someClass.isAnnotationPresent(Component.class)` returns false, even when there is a `@Component` annotation in `someClass.getDeclaredAnnotations()`

Sample:

```
List<Class> componentClasses = new LinkedList<>();
        scans.forEach(s -> componentClasses.addAll(ReflectionUtils.getClassesInPackageRecursively(s)));
        System.out.printf("Classes: %d", componentClasses.size());
        componentClasses.forEach(c -> {
            System.out.println("-".repeat(50));
            System.out.println(Arrays.stream(c.getAnnotations()).map(Annotation::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
            System.out.printf("%s -> %s\n", c.getName(), c.isAnnotationPresent(Component.class));
        });
```

The output:

```
...
@com.ltp.analog.core.annotation.Component()
com.ltp.analog.test.TestOne -> false
...
```

Comment: Side notes: instead of an expensive (regex based) `replaceAll("[.]", "/")` you can do a cheap (char based) `replace('.', '/')`. Instead of copying the `InputStream` byte by byte (worst method ever) to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, you can simply use `return inputStream.readAllBytes();` (but I would still care to close it, see [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)). It’s also worth learning how to use a Stream with `flatMap` and `toList()` instead of using `forEach` and `addAll`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is classloader shenanigans, no doubt.

You have 2 separate classes coincidentally both named `com.ltp.analog.core.annotation.Component`. They aren't the same thing even though they have the same name.

Come again? Yes, really.

Imagine this code:

```
java.lang.String x = (java.lang.String) obj;
```

and when you run that code, you get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.lang.String
```

You'd go: Whaaaa? My JVM is broken!

But no, there is an explanation. And the same thing is happening to you: There are **2 different classes** that are nevertheless both **identically named**: They are both named `com.ltp.analog.core.annotation.Component`. When you call `c.getAnnotations()`, you get an instance back that is from the one 'take' on this class. Its toString still gives you `com.ltp.analog.core.annotation.Component`. When you call `isAnnotationPresent`, your `Component.class` variable is the other 'take'. Thus, the answer is no, for the same reason `.isAnnotationPresent(Override.class)` returns false: Not the same class.

You get here when you use classloaders and you override `loadClass` (you should never be able to get into this situation if you only override `findClass`).

Any class is **actually** defined by *both* of these:

- Its fully qualified name
- Its loader

Its loader is defined by what `thatClassInstance.getClassLoader()` returns, and it is whichever classloader actually invoked `.defineClass(byteArrayWithByteCodeInIt)`.

Thus, you loaded Component once in one loader and then again in another; the one that you get with `c.getAnnotations()` is loaded by the one loader, and the class that the code you pasted is in loaded another.

The solution is more general: You need to be **really really careful** when you override `loadClass`. You can't use any type 'across loaders' unless that type was loaded by a common loader.

Thus, the fix:

**Fix `AnalogClassLoader` - it needs to properly ask its parent loader to load `Component` and not do it itself**.

YOu didn't paste the code of AnalogClassLOader, so I can't give more tips on how to accomplish this. More generally, don't write your own classloaders unless you fully understand them, they are very tricky beasts.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, will check it in a minute, but mb can you give some tip about classloader? The code is included in the question

Comment: Yeah, it actually works for me! Thanks a lot! Fix for me was just calling `parent.loadClass` method.   
Maybe any tips?

Comment: `java.lang.String` is a bad example as packages starting with `java.` are special; unlike other packages they can not be loaded multiple times by different class loaders. Further, `isAnnotationPresent(String.class)` would not compile as `String` is not an annotation type.

Comment: @Holger this is incorrect. You can double-load String if you really really want to; it's just that every classloader framework out there doesn't do it, as all heck breaks loose if you do that.

Comment: Changed the type used into Override.class, thanks @Holger.

Comment: @rzwitserloot The only way for a class loader to create a class, is by calling one of the inherited `defineClass` methods. See [this one, examplary](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#defineClass(java.lang.String,byte%5B%5D,int,int)): “**Throws SecurityException** - If […] or if name begins with "`java.`".” As said, what’s correct for every other qualified name, does not apply to `java. …`.

Comment: @Razor if using `parent.loadClass` solves your problem, the entire `AnalogClassLoader` class is obsolete, as all it does, is precisely loading class definitions found in the parent (system) class loader a second time, as a distinct class, creating the very problem you’re struggling with. If you don’t want that, don’t use a class whose only purpose is precisely that. Just replace your `private static final AnalogClassLoader cl = new AnalogClassLoader();` line with `private static final ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();`